# I can't get anything after mining Diamonds in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have found a HUGE diamond, gold, and redstone cave and every time I mine each one it just destroys it with nothing in return. I am using my Iron Pickaxe,  play on the lowest difficulty, and just recently bought the game. This is very confusing and fustrating for me. Is this a glitch in the game or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you playing in creative mode? If not, are you sure you're using your iron pickaxe?

Comment: I don't know how if i'm in creative world or not. But I know for sure I'm using a iron axe

Comment: If you can destroy anything with one punch, and there's no health and food bar above your hotbar (the little bar with all your tools and things on it) then you're in a creative world.

Comment: I have a health bar but no food bar

Comment: I am playing this on a xbox console by the way.

Comment: Oh, Xbox is a different version, so you won't have a food bar, unfortunately, I don't own the Xbox version so I can't help you with your problem, you'll have to wait for someone else to help

Comment: Shoot, I really do appreciate your help though.

Comment: ¿Does it take an exceedingly long time to mine those blocks? Maybe you're using a rock pickaxe?

Comment: Just to clarify: in the question you say "*I am using my Iron Pickaxe*", but in the comments you say, "*But I know for sure I'm using a iron axe*" These are two very different tools. If you are using an AXE, you'll never collect any ores from mined blocks (except wood), and mining any stone or ore block will take a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Mincraft: XBox 360 Edition can be a little glitchy about placing blocks, rendering lighting, and sometimes mining. But I haven't seen it this bad. Generally restarting Minecraft, or rebooting the XBox, will help the game perform better.

So, I would restart the XBox and try again. If this fails, I might try crafting a new iron pickaxe, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Just to add, playing in single player greatly helps as well. I have had massive problems such as this on local multiplayer, yeah local even, yet very little problems in single player.  Granted I think OP is in single player, but just thought I should add this.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get diamonds by mining them, it's probably because you're in Creative Mode. In order to obtain them, you need to switch to Survival Mode. If you break blocks in Creative Mode, you won't get the reward.